# Hosting website with jquery calender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-hosting

I have i website i used jquery calender in many pages .the calender worked fine for me locally and when used it in dedicated server when uploaded the website on my hosting.com the jquery calender not working but other jquery code running fine.

EDIT:

Code is

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UCCalender11_textDate1").datepicker({ 

 numberOfMonths: 2, 
 showButtonPanel: false, 
 showOn: "button", 
 buttonImage: "../../Images/calendar.gif", 
 buttonImageOnly: true, 
 dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', 
 minDate: 0 

});
```

Comment: What the error console showing.

Comment: No error showing it just the button that show the calender disappeared

Comment: Verify your calendar js-library, css and images path.

Comment: this code for calling the calender<script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {
         
         $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UCCalender11_textDate1").datepicker({
             numberOfMonths: 2,
             showButtonPanel: false,
             showOn: "button",
             buttonImage: "../../Images/calendar.gif",
             buttonImageOnly: true,
                 dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
   , minDate: 0
         });
     

     });
 </script>

Comment: You have your library included in your script. Please view the source of your page. Make sure that all the js files and css are given correctly.

Comment: I ensure that all library work fine but i discovered that client id change from ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UCCalender11_textDate1 to ContentPlaceHolder1_UCCalender11_textDate1 why this changed on hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the ClientID in your jQuery call, which might not always be the same.  You need to retrieve the ClientID of that control from ASP.NET when the page is loading in order for that code to work more consistently.

Something like this:

```
$("#<%= UCCalender11_textDate1.ClientID %>").datepicker({
```

Note that you need to change `UCCalender11_textDate1` to whatever the TextBox control's ID value is in ASP.NET (if that's not it).